# Delete empty rows from all datagridviews

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This way I can delete empty rows from one datagridview.

```
bool Empty = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < PrimaryRadGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Empty = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < PrimaryRadGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (PrimaryRadGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null && PrimaryRadGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        Empty = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (Empty)
                {
                    PrimaryRadGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
```

I got around 6 datagridviews and I want to delete empty rows of all.

Is there a way to delete empty rows from all the datagridviews in the interface??

Comment: Do you want to find every DataGridView in all forms that you have, or is it those 6 instances that you want to clear?

Comment: @Patrick: Just in Form1, i got 6 datgaridview,so i want to delete all the empty rows out of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a method

```
private void clearGrid(DataGridView view) {
    for (int row = 0; row < view.Rows.Count; ++row) {
        bool isEmpty = true;
        for (int col = 0; col < view.Columns.Count; ++col) {
            object value = view.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value;
            if (value != null && value.ToString().Length > 0) {
                isEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isEmpty) {
            // deincrement (after the call) since we are removing the row
            view.Rows.RemoveAt(row--);
        }
    }
}
```

and pass each of your 6 DataGridViews to the method.

```
clearGrid(PrimaryRadGridView);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error at this line, `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value))` Argument object is not assignable toparameter type string.

Comment: Null reference exception un handled. `clearGrid(PrimaryRadGridView);` `private void clearGrid(RadGridView view)`

Comment: I suppose the null reference is inside the clearGrid method? I'm guessing the value from the view cells can be null, in which case you cannot call `ToString` on them. I edited my answer again..

Comment: Half expected that. Basically, removing items in a for loop while it's running is extremely risky. When doing so it's very important to update the value of the integer (row in this case) with -1. Otherwise row will increase where row count will decrease. This means that for each row you delete, the next one will be skipped. Delete row 3 and row 4 will become 3 instead. When row turns to 4 it will handle what was row 5. etc.

Comment: @WozzeC: Point taken. I only copied the code from the OP and used some other variable names. You are completely right with the deincrement.

Comment: To be fair you got quite close without actually testing it :)